# Android billing 4 returns wrong SkuDetails fields

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I updated android billing library from v.3 to v.4.0 in December 2021. After some time in January 2022 my apps starts to receive SkuDetails without "description" field and with undocumented "name" field. I use description field in the app. What's bad is that users get different data randomly. I don't see any documented "name" field in the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails

My analytics shows that sometimes v.3 also receives filled "name" and empty "description".

Was:

```
{"productId":"subs_annual","type":"subs","title":"Premium (APP_NAME)","price":"$12.99","price_amount_micros":12990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","description":"APP_DESCRIPTION","subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y","freeTrialPeriod":"P3D","skuDetailsToken":"APP_TOKEN"}
```

Starts:

```
{"productId":"subs_annual","type":"subs","title":"Premium (APP_NAME)","name":"Premium","price":"$12.99","price_amount_micros":12990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y","freeTrialPeriod":"P3D","skuDetailsToken":"APP_TOKEN"}
```

This means that there is no trust in Android Billing Library versions 3, 4.

I lost part of users and got cancelled subscriptions due to this strange response!
Does anyone know which fields are immutable and can be used in an application without the risk of getting empty data?

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a question on the google issue tracker and they fixed this bug after several weeks.